# Not allow alphabetic value but allow enter,backspace,delete,arrow etc

Tags: jquery

I am calling function on `keypress` where not allow alphabetic value but allow numeric character with enter,backspace,delete,arrow etc

```
function checkIt(s) {
  if (s.match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g')) {
     s = s.replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g', '');
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="return checkIt(this.value)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="return checkIt(this.value)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="return checkIt(this.value)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="return checkIt(this.value)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
```

This code is not working.

Comment: What is that supposed to do. The function will not actually return a value or change anything since it is affecting a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

or you can do something with **[`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)**

```js
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
  if ((e.keyCode < 91 && e.keyCode > 64) || (e.keyCode < 123 && e.keyCode > 96))
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Or using your code

```js
function checkIt(s) {
  s.value=s.value.replace(/[a-z]/gi,'');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkIt(this)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkIt(this)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkIt(this)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkIt(this)" maxlength="4"   class="input-layout" value="10" name="test[]">
```

Comment: Can you please provide solution using this function?

Comment: Added above. pl check

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

1. Regular expressions should not be put in quotes
2. Putting a caret means that you DON'T want it. Since you want numeric and not alphabet, you cannot put them together like that.
3. Your function should return the value.

The answer is already provided by someone else here, but I thought you should know these points.

Comment: I want to use this function and i tried to remove quote but still it is not working